# Friendly Windows Minimum Version in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I can set the minimum version required (for example XP SP3) in Inno-Setup by going

```
MinVersion=0,5.01.2600
```

However, that leads to the rather unfriendly Message Box:

**`This program requires Windows NT version 5.1.2600 or later.`**

Is there any way to have this say instead:

**`This program requires WindowsXP Service Pack 3 or later.`**

Comment: `MinVersion=0,5.1.2600` actually specifies any version of WinXP. To check for a service pack you need this syntax: `MinVersion=0,5.1sp3` (which is XP SP3).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This string is named [`WinVersionTooLowError`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Files/Default.isl#L59) and is defined as

```
This program requires %1 version %2 or later.
```

You can redefine it in the [`[Messages]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_messagessection.htm) section.

Answer (score 0):

```
MinVersion=0,5.01.2600
```

Does not work, try this in [Setup] area, it can be used in quite a number of other areas in inno setup also.

```
MinVersion=0,5.1.2600
```

Comment: This is my preferred syntax:

MinVersion=0,5.01sp3